# Какой нотации принадлежит схема данных в Access? Возможна ли генерация скрипта создания БД со схемы данных?

Tags: база-данных, access, проектирование, erwin

Нужно было сделать ER-модель в нотации IDEF 1x, нарисовал её в Access, и только теперь задумался, что вдруг схема данных в Access не принадлежит к этой нотации. Она принадлежит вообще к какой-нибудь нотации?

И второй вопрос. С этой схемы данных можно сгенерить скрипт создания таблиц, первичных и внешних ключей, как в ERwin?

За компанию, третий. Возможен экспорт модели в ERwin?

Спасибо.

Comment: Access это определенно не тот инструмент, который стоит брать для рисования схемы БД, да еще и в IDEF, да еще и с целью кодогенерации.

Comment: Я понял это, пока делал, неудобная штука, по сравнению даже со старым добрым ERwin)
Мне бы знать хоть ответ на первый вопрос, прокатит ли схема БД как IDEF 1x.